# Navigation from within a UIApplication inheriting class

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have pondered over this for a good few hours now but to no avail. I am trying to add a method to my iPad app that sends it back to the starting screen whenever there is no activity for 120 seconds.

I am very new to both Xamarin and IOS programming so apologies if I'm approaching this from completely the wrong angle.
I have created a class that looks like this

```
[Register("ElectronicReceptionMain")]
public class ElectronicReceptionMain : UIApplication
{       
    public override void SendEvent(UIEvent uievent)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("SendEvent");            
        var allTouches = uievent.AllTouches;
        if(allTouches.Count > 0)
        {
            ResetIdleTimer();
        }            
        base.SendEvent(uievent);
    }

    NSTimer idleTimer;
    void ResetIdleTimer()
    {            
        idleTimer = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120), RefreshScreen);
    }

    void RefreshScreen(NSTimer obj)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Elapsed");                      
        UIStoryboard StoryBoard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
        ViewController uvc = StoryBoard.InstantiateViewController("StartScreenController") as ViewController;
        SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.NavigationController.PushViewController(uvc, true);

    }
}
```

This timer works fine, (the debug message prints out without fail). But I cannot get the NavigationController to be anything other than null obviously resulting in a null reference exception.

I also tried

```
uvc.NavigationController.PushViewController(uvc, true);
```

Same problem. I do have a navigationcontroller in my storyboard and have got successful navigation between screens when going from one UIView to another.

I have stepped through my code 1 line at a time and it is definitely the NaviagtionController that is *null*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RootViewController` should be a `UINavigationViewcontroller`. In Your `AppDelgate` you need to create an instance of the UINavigationViewController and pass your InitialViewControllerInstancein it. And store the instance of the `UINavigationController` in one variable(`navController`) as like below:

**AppDelegate.cs**

```
public UINavigationController navController;

    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        //Here you need to instantiate your first ViewController instance from the storyboard and pass as an argument to the UINavigationController
        navController = new UINavigationController(yourInitialViewControllerInstance);
        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        Window.RootViewController = navController;
        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

        return true;
    }
```

Then if you want to navigate to any other View Controller from any other classes, you would simply access the instance of the `navController` object from `AppDelgate` and navigate as given below:

```
void RefreshScreen(NSTimer obj)
{
      Debug.WriteLine("Elapsed");                      
      UIStoryboard StoryBoard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
      ViewController uvc = StoryBoard.InstantiateViewController("StartScreenController") as ViewController;

     //Navigate using the navController Instance from the appDelgate
     ((AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate).navController.PushViewController(uvc, true);
}
```